# Position HTML element above Android 5.0 browser toolbar

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

I'm trying to position a button element at the bottom of a web page using the following styling:

```
.sticky {
    display: block;
    border: none;
    position: fixed;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

On Chrome for mobile it works fine, but the stock browser for Android has a toolbar at the bottom of the screen that slowly disappears as the user scrolls down.

This means my button is only visible once the user has scrolled enough to make the toolbar disappear, but the intention is to make the button visible at all times.

Is there a way to position the element at the absolute bottom, yet above the toolbar as it moves in and out with scrolling?